# Colorbox popup on schedule

Tags: colorbox

I looked and tried using scripts I found online to set a scheduled colorbox, so far it only worked in Chrome. Below is the script I'm currently using now. I know this must be very basic, but I hope somebody might help or point me the right direction.

**UPDATE**

What I wanted is to have a colorbox displayed every time when people visits, the colorbox will disable it's function when it pass the "ScheduleDate", now only chrome will display the colorbox as planned, ie, firefox and safari seems to not recognize the script. There's no error in the browser console.

```
<script>
    today = new Date();
    today_year = today.getFullYear(); 
    today_month = today.getMonth()+1; 
    today_date = today.getDate(); 
    today_hours = today.getHours(); 
    today_minutes = today.getMinutes(); 
    today_seconds = today.getSeconds(); 

    var CurrentDate = today_year+"-"+today_month+"-"+today_date+"  "+today_hours+":"+today_minutes+":"+today_seconds;
    var ScheduleDate = "2014-10-12 00:00:00";

    if (  (Date.parse(CurrentDate)).valueOf() <= (Date.parse(ScheduleDate)).valueOf())
    {
        $(document).ready(function(){               
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"300px", height:"250px", open:true});             
        });                     
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So what's the issue? SO is not a code review site. Btw, you can move `$(document).ready()` to the start of your script.

Comment: As I said it only worked in chrome. So I post the code because I thought it would be easier for others to understand my issue, I don't know coding, combining them was the best I could do. I think must have done something wrong but I just couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Like what exactly is not working in other browsers? What other browsers have you tried? Are there any error messages in your browser console?

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. What I wanted is to have a colorbox displayed every time when people visits, the colorbox will disable it's function when it pass the "ScheduleDate", now only chrome will display the colorbox as planned, ie, firefox and safari seems to not recognize the script. There's no error in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that I need to do to get your codes to work in FireFox:

1. Wrap all your javascript codes within the `$(document).ready()`.
2. Change the way your `CurrentDate` is constructed and compared.

Run the stack snippet below or refer to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/7dt8p6vj/). Also, I took the CSS from one of their [examples](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/).

```js
// javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var scheduleDate = new Date(2014, 9, 12, 0, 0, 0);

  if (currentDate <= scheduleDate) {
    $.colorbox({
      iframe: true,
      innerWidth: "300px",
      innerHeight: "300px",
      open: true
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.4.33/example1/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.4.33/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
```